# SSRS or SQL - DateDIFF on the same column with certain criteria

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report I created in SSRS. I have it grouped by a column. The Column it is grouped by there are description, details and a date for each.

I want to try and find a datediff between two descriptions for the group but I can't seem to get it right.

I tried to do ::
=DateDiff(dateinterval.Minute,(Fields!date.Value=(Fields!description.Value="description1")),(Fields!date.Value=(Fields!description.Value="description2")))

but it errors out. any idea ? I can supply the code or screenshot if it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute
,lookup("description1",Fields!description.Value,Fields!date.Value,"DataSet1")
,lookup("description2",Fields!description.Value,Fields!date.Value,"DataSet1"))
```

Let me know if this was helpful.